# Please explain what 20 triggers / per user / per script means in the context of 50 scripts-50 files

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, quota

Have been searching for a clear explanation of the quota rule for triggers, but in vain. Can anyone explain if this below will work?

I am creating 50 scripts for 50 files (the code inside each script only differs by each of 50 files id). Each script will have an installable trigger onOpen, where a function referring to one single master file, will be executed. I read the quota 20 triggers / per user per script and cannot make a conclusion regarding my situation based on this rule...( Thanks, all in any case!

Comment: Welcome ot [so]. How the trigger will be created? Will be only one per file or there will me more than one? P.S. 1) While not all questions should have code, usually a [mcve] helps to better understand the issue/problem/concern. 2) In the context of Google Apps Script the term "custom function" usually is used to Apps Script functions to be used in formulas -> https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions

Comment: Thanks, @Rubén, only one per file. And it will be onOpen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For context for other community members in this page: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas you will find this and other limits that apply to Apps Script projects, triggers and function executions.

In your use case this won't be a problem. You will be creating projects and triggers in a 1 : 1 ratio. Apps Script allows up to 20 triggers per project.

You can share that project with someone and this person will be allowed to create 20 more triggers. If you create a new Apps Script project you will be able to create more triggers in the new project.

Trying to create additional triggers will result in this error message:
`Exception: This script has too many triggers. Triggers must be deleted from the script before more can be added.`

Answer (score 0):

I do believe here in this [article](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) where you have read these quota limits presented.

> Triggers  20 / user / script  20 / user / script

20 triggers can be added by a single user on an App Script file, and App Script is a collaborative development tool, multiple users can contribute/collaborate on an App Script project, which means a single App Script project can contain 20> triggers if multiple users are working on the same project/file.

Relating to the setup you have explained, since you'll be only adding an `onOpen()` trigger, technically this only states that you have added a single trigger which is consumed by your Google Account working on the said script file.

These limitations take effect on a per user basis, not on a per script count.